# On Dashboard amounts graph is not working in magento 1.9.4.1

Tags: dashboard, magento-1.9.4.1

We just changed our server and now on our magento dashboard orders graph is working but amounts graph is not working.

I tried many solutions like:
1. updated stats
2. reindexing
3. Changed api url to this:  const API_URL = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart'; 
and many more but nothing worked for me.

This is how the amount graph is looking on dashboard.

[image]

After adding onilab module my graph is looking like this: 
[image]
Actually I think, the main problem is that it is not calculating tax,shipping and revenue for other intervals other than **"This and last year interval"** because for "This and last year interval", amounts graph is looking like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Please Follow this link: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024850172-Switch-from-deprecated-Google-Image-Charts-to-Image-Charts

if graph not working by above patch. then use below module

2) https://github.com/onilab/magento-1-google-api-chart-fix

Hope this will help you.
thanks

Comment: No, actually my Graph.php file in Core/Mage.. is already updated. I have also rechecked it by opening this patch file. If you have any other solution. Please comment

Comment: @RajeevSingh can you try again. i updated my answer. thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check.